# What is the idiom for "trouble came from somewhere no one expected it to come from"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an English idiom/expression for "a problem came from a place no one expected it from"?

As in "we were not even paying attention to this part, because it was supposed to be simple & reliable, yet it generated the most problem!"

There's an expression in my mother tongue (Russian) that goes "oh comes the trouble from where least expected", is there an English version of this?

I would say "out of the blue", but this just means "unexpected" without stressing the "unexpected *origin*" of it.

UPDATE: I probably phrased my question poorly. I don't just mean "unexpected trouble". I mean **"we were EXPECTING trouble, but we were LOOKING THE WRONG WAY"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem came from left field

> **come from left field.**
> To originate from a surprising or strange place. ("Left field" is the metaphorical origin of something uncommon, unpopular, or otherwise strange.).
> That suggestion certainly came from left field! How did you come up with that one?
>
> - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+from+left+field

PS. I know this was originally a baseball metaphor, but we still use it in the UK where few of us understand or care about baseball!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may find the following idiomatic expression useful in your context:

***take (someone or something) by surprise***:

> happen when someone is not prepared or is expecting something different.

- *The problem took us by surprise.*

Answer (score 1):

In buzzy news outlets that report on politics, journalists will often refer to difficulties arising from an unexpected origin as so-and-so's "problem from Hell".

Comment: A "Problem from hell" is so called because it's difficult to deal with rather than being from an unexpected origin.

Comment: I thought it also implied unexpected difficulty, either because overlooked or left unresolved for long enough to worsen - or a surprisingly consequential problem that at first appeared benign or immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

[In the end,]  _________ [e.g. the biggest problem] came up where we least expected it.

Or: ... came up where it was least expected.

Those are the phrases I've most often seen for the scenario you described.

Answer (score 1):

A [black swan event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory) describes an event that comes out of nowhere and has a major effect, though they are only generally trouble.

Answer (score 0):

[blank] came "**out of nowhere**" / [blank] came "**Out of the Blue**" <-different phrasing of-> "**Fell out of the sky**" / [blank] "**got blind-sided**" /
(the following make the subject the one being surprised rather than the object that surprised [closer to the updated question]): [blank] was "**caught off guard**" <-similar to -> "**caught flat-footed**"

Comment: Most of these seem to be ruled out by the update to the question.

Comment: None of these indicate trouble, though, just a suddenness with which something happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Curve, Curveball**

> **A surprise, often completely and totally unexpected, and usually unpleasant.**

*The curveball is a pitch in baseball designed to fool the batter by curving unexpectedly. *AHDI* dates this usage to the mid-20th century.*

[*"Because of my personal story, I'm very interested in illness. One thing we discovered as a family is that when you're **thrown a curveball** like cancer or multiple sclerosis, often people do not know what to do first". – Meredith Vieira, quoted by Jeff Chu, Time, 27 August 2006.*]

[*"Desormeaux chalked up the latest loss, his second so close to the Triple Crown, to another twist in a life so full of them. 'Life **throws curves**,' he said, 'Some of us hit it, and some of us will sulk around. We've continued to hit the curveball"'.*  *The New York Times, 8 June 2008.*]

{*Wikipedia*}

Answer (score -1):

There is a Romanian proverb which I find rendered everywhere by the English saying:

> Where we least think, there goeth the hare away.

However, I cannot find a link where the meaning of the saying is explained. I only found it listed [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hOOkCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT202&lpg=PT202&dq=%22Where%20we%20least%20think,%20there%20goeth%20the%20HARE%20away%22&source=bl&ots=cEg6Nn_pFm&sig=ACfU3U1ww_5G2SMHwVttfEAySBShU56MSA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivttrU0on1AhVEilwKHda7AqAQ6AF6BAgeEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Where%20we%20least%20think%2C%20there%20goeth%20the%20HARE%20away%22&f=false) (entry 1336) together with its equivalents in some Romance languages. I have also found it listed in an [*old handbook of proverbs*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zkFIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA564&lpg=PA564&dq=%22Where%20we%20least%20think,%20there%20goeth%20the%20HARE%20away%22&source=bl&ots=SkH4klHZBg&sig=ACfU3U0-Gy4MlxA-TTeDuVL0RtcYE-wxMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivttrU0on1AhVEilwKHda7AqAQ6AF6BAgdEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Where%20we%20least%20think%2C%20there%20goeth%20the%20HARE%20away%22&f=false) compiled by Henry George Bohn in 1860.

The saying explains itself in a way, but it basically means that something comes up from where you least expect it.

Comment: Seems quite obsolete in 2021.

Answer (score -1):

The problem *came in under the radar*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under%20the%20radar)
>
> under the radar:
>
> not getting attention : unnoticed
>
> "He tried to stay under the radar as he went about his business"

The saying originates from the days when a low-flying incoming aircraft could escape detection by radar because the radar reflections from objects near the ground were non-existent because of earth shadowing or object shadowing, or were too weak or too confused to be seen reliably..

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they disagree with Merriam Webster?

Comment: I like this. I’ve also heard it as snuck under the radar. +1

Answer (score -1):

Well, technically it's not English but (wait I do have an English answer below sort of) there is a saying in Cebuano

> [ang gaba dili magsaba](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ang_gaba_dili_magsaba)

Wiktionary says

1. Literally: “[bad] karma comes without a noise”.
2. Punishment for one's wrongdoings or transgressions will come unexpectedly

It's like '**what goes around comes around**' but with an additional qualifier 'without warning'

Answer (score -2):

Possible idiomatic ways (if not using idioms) to put this (but note that the problem needs to be mentioned) are:

- 'A problem arose from an unexpected source / quarter.'
- 'We encountered a problem from an unlikely source.'

> Superstars Adele, Elton John, Ed Sheeran, and Abba are also in the
> running, say the bookies.
>
> But they now face competition from an unlikely quarter. The Church of
> England has announced its first Christmas single ....

[[Guardian; Nov 2021](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2021/nov/30/christmas-number-1-ladbaby-and-adele-face-competition-from-the-church)]

> ... transmission of infection from an unexpected source mean[s that]
> infection outbreaks do still occur

[[University of Cambridge: PHG Foundation](https://www.phgfoundation.org/briefing/protecting-patients-from-healthcare-associated-infections-a-role-for-genomics)]